# Не отправляется файл через почту

Tags: php, email

Все данные отправляются кроме файла

```
<input class="igroup-input" type="file" name="fileFF[]" multiple id="fileFF" accept="image/*">    


<?php
            if (isset ($_POST['nameFF'])) {
                $to = "1@gmail.com";
                $from = $_POST['nameFF'];
                $subject = "Запрос на подачу рекламы с ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
                $message = "Регион: ".$_POST['nameF']."\nГород: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\nНазвание компании: ".$_POST['nameComp']."\nКатегория: ".$_POST['nameFF1']."\nНомер телефона: ".$_POST['telFF']."\nСсылка ВК: ".$_POST['vk']."\nИмя менеджера: ".$_POST['nameMen']."\nДата и время: ".$_POST['loginFF']."\nIP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                  $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
      $filesize = '';
      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
      $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
      $message="
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

    --$boundary
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    $message";
      for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['fileFF']['name']);$i++) {
          if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
             $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])));
             $filename = $_FILES['fileFF']['name'][$i];
             $filetype = $_FILES['fileFF']['type'][$i];
             $filesize += $_FILES['fileFF']['size'][$i];
             $message.="

    --$boundary
    Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

    $attachment";
         }
       }
       $message.="
    --$boundary--";

      if ($filesize < 10000000) {
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        $output = '<script>alert("Ваше сообщение получено, спасибо!");</script>';
      } else {
        $output = '<script>alert("Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 10 МБ.");</script>';
      }
    }
    ?>
$(".fofm1").submit(function() {
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: str,
        success: function(msg) {
            if(msg == 'ok') {
                $('.popup2, .overlay').css('opacity','1');
                $('.popup2, .overlay').css('visibility','visible');
                $('.popup').css({'opacity':'0','visibility':'hidden'});
            }
            else {
                $('.popup2 .window').html('<h5>Ошибка</h5><p>Сообщение не отправлено, убедитесь в правильности заполнение полей</p>');
                $('.popup2, .overlay').css('opacity','1');
                $('.popup2, .overlay').css('visibility','visible');
                $('.popup').css({'opacity':'0','visibility':'hidden'});
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Возможна проблема в ajax(

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что метод `.serialize()` не умеет корректно обрабатывать файлы. Об этом явно сказано в [документации](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), а именно:

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. **Data from file select elements**
>   **is not serialized.**

Посмотрите на примеры вот [отсюда](https://itchief.ru/lessons/javascript/formdata-javascript-object-to-encode-form-data). Там подробно разобран как раз ваш случай с отправкой файла.

Для лучшего понимания, как именно происходит загрузка файлов через AJAX, рекомендую посмотреть также вот эту [страничку](http://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress). Там примеры даны на обычно JS, но зато подробно описано - что и почему.

Comment: Хорошо, а еще можно сделать два ajax срипта на две формы? Вставляю два разных ajax. но он работает только с одной

Comment: Опишите - как вставляете, как работает, и как не работает. Лучше с примерами кода и описанием работы. Мне кажется вы уже поняли, как сделать то, что вам нужно )

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, была проверка на нажатия кнопки, но кнопки не было. Пока не вкурил, как сделать загрузку файла, попробовал заменить serialize, на formdata, но не работает

Comment: Продолжайте разбираться. Тысячи AJAX-загрузчиков на сайтах не могут ошибаться ) Если не получится самому, оформите вопрос с примерами, попробуем разобраться. Вам поможет отладчик браузера (покажет, что отправилось) и отладка серверной части (покажет, что принялось). Проблема может быть где угодно.

Comment: Вот я оформил, отправляются все кроме файла, как будто его нет

Comment: Почему опять в AJAX перед отправкой форма упаковывается через `var str = $(this).serialize();`, хотя вам ясно и понятно сказали - этот метод не работает с файлами - и **не должен**. `$().serialize()`  пропускает все `input` с типом `file`, он так работает. Еще раз посмотрите на ответ, на три ссылки в нем, там подробно разобран именно ваш случай.